# C++ - Error while usign arrays as parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, string, stdstring

I made a array of words and made a function to return a random word from the array. But it shows this error -

```
hangman.cpp: In function 'std::__cxx11::string get_random_word(std::__cxx11::string*)':
hangman.cpp:17:33: warning: 'sizeof' on array function parameter 'words' will return size of 'std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
     size_t length = sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]);
                                 ^
hangman.cpp:15:47: note: declared here
 std::string get_random_word(std::string words[])
                                               ^
```

Here is the code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

std::string get_random_word(std::string words[]);

int main()
{   
    srand(time(0));
    std::string words[] = {"cpp", "python", "java"};
    std::cout << get_random_word(words);
    return 0;
}

std::string get_random_word(std::string words[])
{
    size_t length = sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]);
    return words[rand() % length];
}
```

Comment: The error seems to be pretty clear. You're using `sizeof` incorrectly with `sizeof(words)`, which returns the size of a pointer to an array, which is not what you're intending to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator may not be doing exactly what you think. According to cppreference: *(`sizeof`) Yields the size in bytes of the object representation of type.* This may include any internal members needed for the class, and not just how many characters are used in the string for example. std::string has the `size()` and `length()` functions for this, which are the same, and instead of using an array you can use a vector that also provides a `size()` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

std::string get_random_word(std::vector<std::string>& words)
{
    return words[rand() % words.size()];
}

int main()
{   
    srand(time(0));
    std::vector<std::string> words = {"cpp", "python", "java"};
    std::cout << get_random_word(words);
    return 0;
}
```